# SQL many to many relationship with 3 relations

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is it possible to make a many to many relationship (with a new table) and include 3 relations, from 3 tables? And if yes is it a good practice?

Answer (score 0):

If you have 3 tables, you should only need 2 relations. Maybe try a join similar to the following:

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/71361/how-to-join-3-tables-together-given-2-many-to-many-relationships-tables-in-betwe